# How to make conditional classes using Material-UI useStyles?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to reproduce this logic but using material-ui useStyle

```
<div className={'container ' + (state.unlocked ? 'containerUnlocked' : '')}>
```

I imagined it would be something similar to this :

```
<div className={`${classes.container} + ${state.unlocked} ? ${classes.spacious} : ''`}>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: That's because there is no logic in the second example. It's outputting a string that looks like a ternary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work :

```
<div className={`${classes.container} ${(condition) ? classes.classTrue : classes.classFalse }`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

material-ui comes with `clsx`, which can be used to add classes optionally. just import it and use it.

```
import clsx from 'clsx'
...


<div className={clsx(classes.container, {[classes.spacious]:state.unlocked})}>
```